# Angular 12: canActivate Guard not working on page refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-guards, angular12

My canActivate guard works like this: if the current (fire auth) user has a user profile, then he can access the route. Otherwise, I route him to the profile creation page.

This works perfectly fine, unless I refresh the page!

Guard:

```js
export class UserProfileGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (this.authService.userProfile) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['user/createprofile']).then();
    return false;
  }


}
```

Auth Service:

```js
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
  public userProfile: UserProfile | null = null;
  private subscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(public fire: AngularFireAuth, private httpService: HttpHandlerService) {
    this.subscription = this.fire.authState.subscribe(fireAuthUser => {
      if (fireAuthUser) {
        this.httpService.getMyProfile().subscribe((profile: UserProfile) => {
            this.userProfile = profile;
          })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

So if I'm on a protected route and refresh the page, I'm always sent to the profile creation page, even if a profile exists.

I fear that the guard checks too early in case of refresh, in a time in which the profile is not yet fetched by the Auth Service.

Can you please give me some assistance on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your guard is waiting for the API to get the data.

```
export class UserProfileGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private httpService: YourService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return checkUser();
  }

  checkUser(): Observable<boolean> {
   this.httpService.getMyProfile().subscribe((profile: UserProfile) => {
            // Do your if the profile exists check
            return true if they have profile
            return false if they don't
          })
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

canActivate accepts Observable as return type. So instead of directly returning true/false you can return Observable
Also instead of writing router.navigate you can return a UrlTree which will auto redirect in that case.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.getUserAuth().pipe(
    map((authResponse) => {
       if(authResponse) {
          return true;
       }
       return this.router.createUrlTree(['user, 'createprofile']).toString()
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      return this.router.createUrlTree(['user, 'createprofile']).toString()
    }))
  }
```

In your service you can add a method to return auth observable.

```
userProfile = null;

getUserAuth: () => {
   if(userProfile) {
     return of(userProfile)
   }

   return this.fire.authState.pipe(switchMap((fireAuthUser) => {
     if(fireAuthUser) {
       return this.httpService.getMyProfile()
     }
     return throwError('No Auth User found!')
   }), tap((profile) => this.userProfile = profile)
}
```